# Perl find - Returning out of memory

Tags: perl, find, out-of-memory

I'm trying to use a perl command line to display the top 10 files from a directory of 690GB. Since it has a very long list of files, my command is ending with Out of Memory error

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE '
    find(sub { say -s $_, " $File::Find::name" }, "/opt/app")
' \ | sort -nr | head -n10
```

How can i optimize this command to get the desired output. I have used the find command to list the files, however its taking atleast 15mins to process.

Comment: Are you sure that perl is the one getting out of memory? I would rather suspect that this is sort since (contrary to perl) it needs to keep all the data in memory in order to sort it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  `sort` _doesn't_ (have to) take all data memory ..? I recently sorted files of over 1 billion lines (100 Gb) and never used much RAM. I used the external `sort` for that reason

Comment: How much memory do you have? How many files? What system?

Comment: @zdim: maybe you are right. But File::Find should not consume much memory either. And the OP does not seem to know which part of the command is actually dying, i.e. perl, sort or head.

Comment: @zdim  There are 3393854 files
32GB memory
Its an AIX system

Comment: Thank you.  I'm baffled with the memory error, as you only use filenames.  Even if they were 100 bytes on average on 3 million that'd be 300 Mb. But as for speed, it's got to take time.  If it's all ascii note that `LC_ALL=C sort ...` speeds things up a lot.  I don't know about `find`'s performance but I don't see why Perl's find would be faster.

Comment: Since it's piped into `sort` it may be trying to pass the whole list, and then it may be hitting some limit. But I don't know that you'd get 'Out of memory' error for _that_. Perhaps the best way is to parcel the job, along the lines of [Сухой27's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50423119/4653379), all in a script. Or put together a Unix command and wait :)

Comment: @AnoopKumarKR: please find out first which of the three processes (perl, sort, head) actually dies because of out of memory.

Comment: the find command dies because of Out of memory... :(

Comment: @Anoop: Does it still fail if you don't output to a pipe?

Comment: yes, I have ran only till this part of the code to see whether its listing the files atleast, but receiving the Out of memory message..!! 


perl -MFile::Find -wE '
    find(sub { say -s $_, " $File::Find::name" }, "/opt/app")
'

Comment: It is strange that perl runs out of memory, within a total of a few hundred Mb of filenames.  Can you confirm that it actually uses all that RAM, by watching memory usage while the (Perl only) program is running?  One thought is to check with `ulimit -a` whether there are unreasonable limits set.  (You can change them with `ulimit -d`.)  Btw, what is your Perl version?

Comment: @zdim

$ ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        4194304
memory(kbytes)       32768
coredump(blocks)     2097151
nofiles(descriptors) unlimited
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited

Comment: @zdim perl v5.10.1

Comment: Thank you -- that's 4Gb for memory, which is plenty.  Can you establish how much memory the Perl part is taking during execution? Like, watch memory consumption on the system while it's running.  The other thing to do would be to run on subdirectories, and process more and more at each run so to see when it breaks.

Answer (score 4):

Trading speed for memory (untested),

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE'
    find(sub{
        @s = sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } [ -s $_, $File::Find::name ], @s;
        splice(@s, 10);
    }, "/opt/app");
    say @$_ for @s;
'
```

Comment: Needs `-s ...`. Then, I think that it needs to sort on `->[1]`, otherwise when `chdir` is done to the next directory the previously stored `$_` won't be good filenames for the `sort`.

Comment: Tnx, updated; it should sort descending based od file size.

Comment: @Borodin Shouldn't that be `$#s = 9;` ?

Comment: Try replacing `splice(@s, 10)` with `$#s = 9`.

Comment: check answer history; @ikegami already addressed the issue with `$#array` lvalue performance and warnings for newer perls.